# How to change background color for active tab in Bootstrap 3 navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have navigation bar with few items. Each tab has class active assigned if it's currently selected. If that has class  active I would like to set background color to that tab. Here is example:

```css
div.admin-box {
 background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

.active a {
  background-color: #E0E0E0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <!-- Tab 1 -->
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane fade in active admin-box">
      Tab 1 content.
    </div>
    <!-- Tab 2 -->
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane fade admin-box">
      Tab 2 content
    </div>
    <!-- Tab 3 -->
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane fade admin-box">
      Tab 3 content.
    </div>
    <!-- Tab 4 -->
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-pane fade admin-box">
      Tab 4 content.
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see each tab container has background color. So selected tab should have the same background color to match containers background. Is there a way to achieve that with pure CSS or JS has to be involved as well? If anyone knows easy way to do this please let me know.

Comment: I've just re-read your question and think I misunderstood with my first comment. So, are you looking to automatically match the background colour of the tab no matter what the colour is? I.e, if the background colour of the tab is red, copy that to the link?

Comment: @Lewis I found solution. Please check the updated version.

Comment: Ah, okay - just hard coded colours. That makes sense.

Comment: you shouldn't do that. it will globally override anything that follows that nesting `.active a` (unless you are using CSS modules). you should at least define a scope `.nav-tabs .active a`

Comment: @dysfunc This is what I have `ul.nav-tabs li.active a {  background-color:#E0E0E0 !important;}`

Comment: @espresso_coffee good :). If you include the CSS I provided in my example after bootstrap you won't need to use `!important`

Comment: this is the change working without using `!important` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMBXqq

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to modify the CSS for `.nav-tabs > li.active > a`

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a, 
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, 
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

You can also modify the LESS variable in v3 `@navbar-default-link-active-bg` and `@navbar-default-link-active-color`

You should include this CSS change after your bootstrap stylesheet include or sass import to avoid using `!important` to override

[DEMO WITHOUT USING IMPORTANT](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMBXqq)

Comment: Try this `.active a { background-color: #E0E0E0 !important;}`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working example of what you are trying: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thezeeshantariq/43a8z6ok/8/)

```
.nav-tabs li.active  a{
  display: block;
  background-color: tomato !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if anyone looking for the same in Bootstrap 5 in future.

```
.nav-tabs button.active {
    background-color: tomato !important;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add   `.active a { background-color: #E0E0E0 !important;}` to your css. It will make the color of tab same as containers. Below is working code:

```css
div.admin-box {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

.active a { background-color: #E0E0E0 !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <!-- Tab 1 -->
  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane fade in active admin-box">
    Tab 1 content.
  </div>
  <!-- Tab 2 -->
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane fade admin-box">
    Tab 2 content
  </div>
  <!-- Tab 3 -->
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane fade admin-box">
    Tab 3 content.
  </div>
  <!-- Tab 4 -->
  <div id="tab-4" class="tab-pane fade admin-box">
    Tab 4 content.
  </div>
</div>
```